# Is it possible to re-implement `Enum` deriving using GHC generics

Tags: haskell, generics, enums

Is it possible to re-implement deriving of `Enum` type class using GHC
generics?

At first, it looks easy:

```hs
data Foo -- representation without metadata (wrong):
  = Foo  -- L1 U1
  | Bar  -- R1 (L1 U1)
  | Baz  -- R1 (R1 (L1 U1))
  | Quux -- R1 (R1 (R1 U1))
  deriving (Show, Eq, Generic)

-- Rep Foo p = (U1 :+: (U1 :+: (U1 :+: U1))) p

instance Enum Foo where
  toEnum   = undefined -- FIXME
  fromEnum = gfromEnum . from

class GEnum f where
  gfromEnum :: f p -> Int

instance GEnum U1 where
  gfromEnum U1 = 0

instance GEnum f => GEnum (M1 i t f) where
  gfromEnum (M1 x) = gfromEnum x

instance (GEnum x, GEnum y) => GEnum (x :+: y) where
  gfromEnum (L1 x) = gfromEnum x
  gfromEnum (R1 y) = 1 + gfromEnum y
```

However, this is not going to work:

```hs
λ> fromEnum Foo
0
λ> fromEnum Bar
1
λ> fromEnum Baz
1
λ> fromEnum Quux
2
```

This is because we can't rely on how arguments of `(:+:)` are grouped. In
this case it seems they are nested like this:

```hs
((U1 :+: U1) :+: (U1 :+: U1)) p
```

So, is it possible to derive `Enum` using `Generics`? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC derives `Generic` such that the L and R variants form a tree where the leaves are in `Enum` order. Consider the following example (with trimmed output):

```
ghci> data D = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Generic)
ghci> from A
L1 (L1 U1)
ghci> from B
L1 (R1 U1)
ghci> from C
R1 (L1 U1)
ghci> from D
R1 (R1 (L1 U1))
ghci> from E
R1 (R1 (R1 U1)))
```

Notice that if you arranged these as a tree, `` toEnum `map` [1..] `` is going to be the left to right traversal of the leaves. With that intuition, we'll start by defining a `GLeaves` class which counts the number of leaves that a generic type (not a value!) has in its tree.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, PolyKinds, TypeApplications, TypeOperators,
             DefaultSignatures, FlexibleContexts, TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Generics
import Data.Proxy

class GLeaves f where
  -- | Counts the number of "leaves" (i.e. U1's) in the type `f`
  gSize :: Proxy f -> Int

instance GLeaves U1 where
  gSize _ = 1

instance GLeaves x => GLeaves (M1 i t x) where
  gSize _ = gSize (Proxy :: Proxy x)

instance (GLeaves x, GLeaves y) => GLeaves (x :+: y) where
  gSize _ = gSize (Proxy :: Proxy x) + gSize (Proxy :: Proxy y)
```

Now, we are in shape to define `GEnum`. As is usual with this setup, we define our class `Enum'` and have default signatures that rely on `GEnum`.

```
class Enum' a where
  toEnum' :: Int -> a
  fromEnum' :: a -> Int

  default toEnum' :: (Generic a, GEnum (Rep a)) => Int -> a
  toEnum' = to . gToEnum

  default fromEnum' :: (Generic a, GEnum (Rep a)) => a -> Int
  fromEnum' = gFromEnum . from

class GEnum f where
  gFromEnum :: f p -> Int
  gToEnum :: Int -> f p
```

Finally, we get to the good stuff. For `U1` and `M1`, `gFromEnum` and `gToEnum` are both straightforward. For `:+:`, `gFromEnum` needs to find all of the leaves to the left of it, so if it is the right subtree we add the size of the left subtree (and if it is the left subtree we add nothing). Similarly, `gToEnum`, checks whether it belong in the left or right subtree by checking if it is smaller than the number of leaves in the left subtree.

```
instance GEnum U1 where
  gFromEnum U1 = 0

  gToEnum n = if n == 0 then U1 else error "Outside enumeration range"

instance GEnum f => GEnum (M1 i t f) where
  gFromEnum (M1 x) = gFromEnum x

  gToEnum n = M1 (gToEnum n)

instance (GLeaves x, GEnum x, GEnum y) => GEnum (x :+: y) where
  gFromEnum (L1 x) = gFromEnum x
  gFromEnum (R1 y) = gSize (Proxy :: Proxy x) + gFromEnum y

  gToEnum n = let s = gSize (Proxy :: Proxy x)
              in if n < s then L1 (gToEnum n) else R1 (gToEnum (n - s))
```

Finally, you can test this in GHCi:

```
ghci> :set -XDeriveAnyClass -XDeriveGeneric
ghci> data D = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Show, Generic, Enum, Enum')
ghci> toEnum `map` [0 .. 4] :: [D]
[A,B,C,D,E]
ghci> toEnum' `map` [0 .. 4] :: [D]
[A,B,C,D,E]
ghci> fromEnum `map` [A .. E] :: [Int]
[A,B,C,D,E]
ghci> fromEnum' `map` [A .. E] :: [Int]
[A,B,C,D,E]
```

#### Performance

You may be thinking to yourself: this is super inefficient! We end up recalculating a bunch of sizes over and over - the worst case performance is at least `O(n^2)`. The catch is that (hopefully), GHC will be able to optimize/inline the hell out of our specific `Enum'` instances until there is *nothing left of the initial `Generic` structure*.

Answer (score 3):

Enum is one of many examples that are slightly awkward to write using the standard GHC Generics representation, because a lot of the structure of datatypes is left implicit (e.g. how sum and product constructors are nested, and where metadata occurs).

With [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop), you can (re-)define generic Enum instances in a slightly more straight-forward way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, DataKinds, DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, GADTs, PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, TypeOperators #-}

import Generics.SOP
import qualified GHC.Generics as GHC
```

We define a type synonym that captures what it means to be an enumeration type:

```
type IsEnumType a = All ((~) '[]) (Code a)
```

(Unfortunately, the `(~) '[]` construction triggers a bug in GHC 8.0.1, but it works fine in GHC 8.0.2.) In generics-sop, the *code* of a datatype is a type-level list of lists. The outer list contains an element for each constructor, the inner lists contain the types of the constructor arguments. The `IsEnumType` constraint says that all of the inner lists have to be empty, which means that none of the constructors must have any arguments.

```
gfromEnum :: (Generic a, IsEnumType a) => a -> Int
gfromEnum = conIndex . unSOP . from
  where
    conIndex :: NS f xs -> Int
    conIndex (Z _) = 0
    conIndex (S i) = 1 + conIndex i
```

The function `from` turns a value into a sum-of-products representation, and `unSOP` strips the outer constructor. We then have a sum structure to traverse. The `NS` datatype representing n-ary sums has constructors `Z` and `S` that indicate exactly which constructor is being used, so we can simply traverse and count.

```
gtoEnum :: (Generic a, IsEnumType a) => Int -> a
gtoEnum i =
  to (SOP (apInjs_NP (hcpure (Proxy @ ((~) '[])) Nil) !! i))
```

Here, the `apInjs_NP (hcpure ...)` call produces the representations of
empty constructor applications for all constructors of the datatype. Unlike the `gfromEnum` function, this actually makes use of the `IsEnumType` constraint to be type correct (because we rely on the fact that none of the constructors take any arguments). We then selected the `i`-th constructor out of the list and turn it back from the generic representation to the actual type by applying first `SOP` and then `to`.

To apply it to your sample type, you have to instantiate it to both GHC's and generic-sop's `Generic` classes (or you can use TH for this, too):

```
data Foo = Foo | Bar | Baz | Quux
  deriving (Show, Eq, GHC.Generic)

instance Generic Foo
```

Then you can test it:

```
GHCi> gfromEnum Baz
2
GHCi> gtoEnum 2 :: Foo
Baz
```

If you want, you can make `gfromEnum` and `gtoEnum` the default definitions for an Enum-like class, just as with GHC Generics.